# Count records where the date is last month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count

I have a table like this

[image: Table]

And then I want to add a column besides Total column. The column is `LastMonthTotal` with the same record but the date is last month before. How can I do that?

Here's the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ERA_Report2]
(
    [RESULT] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CLASSIFICATION_2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ARMADA] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CDAREA] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BRAND] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [MODEL] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Shift] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [AST_POINT] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SOURCE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [AREA] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [POST DATE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PRICE] [float] NULL,
    [DISC] [float] NULL,
    [Net Payment] [float] NULL
)
```

My query is like this:

```
WITH step1 AS (
SELECT [RESULT],[CLASSIFICATION_2],[ARMADA],[CDAREA],[BRAND],[MODEL],[Shift],[AST_POINT],[SOURCE],[AREA]
      ,CONVERT(DATE, [POST DATE]) AS [POST DATE],COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM [AstraWorldDB].[dbo].[ERA_Report2]
GROUP BY [RESULT],[CLASSIFICATION_2],[ARMADA],[CDAREA],[BRAND],[MODEL],[Shift],[AST_POINT],[SOURCE],[AREA]
        ,[POST DATE]
),

step2 AS (
SELECT [RESULT],[CLASSIFICATION_2],[ARMADA],[CDAREA],[BRAND],[MODEL],[Shift],[AST_POINT],[SOURCE],[AREA]
      ,[POST DATE],Total      
      ,CASE
            WHEN MONTH([POST DATE]) > DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [POST DATE]))
            THEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM step1 
                  WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, [POST DATE]) = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [POST DATE])) AND
                        DATEPART(YEAR, [POST DATE]) = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [POST DATE]))
                  )
            ELSE '0'
       END AS LastMonthTotal
FROM step1 
)

SELECT *
FROM step2
WHERE AREA = 'DPS'
ORDER BY [POST DATE]
```

but it keeps returning 0 when it shouldn't. This is the result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn2Ui.png)

where `POST DATE = 2020-02-01`, `LastMonthTotal` must be 2.

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: i already edit my question, please anyone help, thankyou and appreciate it! @ZoharPeled

Comment: Sorry, but I can't read the data in your images, nor can I copy it and paste into a test environment. If you could [edit] again to provider *proper* sample data, that might help you get an answer.

Comment: because my office still using SQL Server 2008 R2, and im an interns at my offfice @GordonLinoff

Comment: how can i provide u proper sample data? im new in stackoverflow. thankyou @ZoharPeled

Comment: Did you see the link in my first comment? it's all described there...

Comment: i already add DDL, i dont have DML because i export it from excel, can u help with only DDL? @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all supported versions of SQL Server, you would use `LAG()` -- assuming that every month has data:

```
select t.*,
       lag(total) over (partition by [RESULT],[CLASSIFICATION_2], [ARMADA],[CDAREA], [BRAND], [MODEL], [Shift], [AST_POINT], [SOURCE], [AREA] order by [POST DATE]) as prev_month_total
from <your table> t;
```

This seems like a reasonable assumption.

In older versions, you would presumably use a `join`:

```
select t.*, tprev.total
from <your table> t left join
     <your table> tprev
     on tprev.result = t.result and . . . -- all the columns that define the group
        tprev.post_date = dateadd(month, -1, t.post_date)
```

Comment: im using sql server 2008, which is not recognize LAG() function. but thankyou for ur answer, appreciate it!

Comment: i only have 1 table, so there is no tprev.total coloumn. i have to create new coloumn for LastMonthTotal. i tried ur query but it didnt work

Comment: sorry, it actually works. but some row returns null that shouldnt be null, idk why, maybe u know the cause of the problem?

Comment: @JordanChai . . . It would return `NULL` because you don't have a "previous month" for all combinations.  The `NULL` should probably be treated as `0` -- `coalesce(tprev.total, 0)`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! i got another problem. can i show rows that not match with the previous month also? so, rows that not match will return column of Total 0, and return column of LastMonthTotal based on the value?